# Using Selenium and phpUnderControl on a Linux headless box?

Tags: php, selenium, automated-tests, phpundercontrol

I am trying to integrate Selenium and phpUnderControl on a headless Linux box, but haven't found anything about it. I can run Selenium with Xvfb, and phpUnderControl is running OK. My question is: how to configure phpuc to execute selenium tests, and show their results on its webpage? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium tests have to be written - the best approach is to use the [Selenium extension for PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.1/en/selenium.html). The results will be part of the unit tests report in phpUnderControl.